# Django forms date validation failing on localization

Tags: django, forms, validation

Hi I have a form such as:

```
class GraphForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    startdate = forms.DateField(
                label=ugettext_lazy('Start Date'),
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": 'YYYY-MM-DD'}),
                )
    enddate = forms.DateField(
                label=ugettext_lazy('End Date'),
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": 'YYYY-MM-DD'}),
                )
    ...
```

The trouble is I am working with an international site using Djangos internationalization and localization. The form works fine in English but if the language is switched to Spanish the date fields fail validation, due to the format. Is there any way to bypass the localization and validate on the same format regardless of language selection?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the answer is surprisingly simple:

```
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d' 

class GraphForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    startdate = forms.DateField(
            label=ugettext_lazy('Start Date'),
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": 'YYYY-MM-DD'}),
            input_formats=[date_format,],
            )
    enddate = forms.DateField(
            label=ugettext_lazy('End Date'),
            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": 'YYYY-MM-DD'}),
            input_formats=[date_format,],
            )
    ...
```

Hope this helps someone else.